# What is the correct approach to show the image without distortion in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, image, sdwebimage

I have a very fundamental question hence not posting any code.

**OverView**

I have a collection view which makes use of custom layout which I have written. All this custom layout does is it applies some maths and finds out the optimal number of cells to place on screen based on screen width and tries to round off the additional pixels using padding. As a result most of my cells size vary when the collection view changes its orientation especially on a device like iPad Pro. What I mean is if the cell size is 300 x 300 in portrait it might become 320 x 300 something like that in landscape. (They are not exact values just trying to give an idea)

Every single cell has imageView in it and image needs to be downloaded from server. I am making use of SDWebImage. Images downloaded are way bigger than my cells and I don't want to load such big images into memory, hence I have decided that I'll be resizing the image once it is downloaded before putting it on to SDWebImageCache.

**Issue**

Now as my cells sizes are changing based on device orientation, in order to make the image look pixel perfect I'll have to resize the image every time device rotates for each cell. But that will lead to bad performance.

**Solutions I have figured out**

1. I'll have to cache two images each one for one orientation in SDWeImageCache but thats again will increase memory footprint of the app.
2. Find the biggest size cell will get among various orientation and resize the image to that size and then use the same image for all the smaller cell size with image view having its mode set to AspectToFit.

Please suggest me what is the correct approach. I don't need the code, just need idea.

Comment: 2. seems the easiest. I would go with 2 and see if the result looks good enough (I'm betting that it will). If not go with 1.

Comment: @deadbeef : Thanks for the suggestion :) The only issue with solution 2 is that I don't know the max size of cell until user rotates the device to all the orientations :( or I'll have to calculate upfront the sizes for all orientation which again should be fine as it involves hardly few maths equations and should be light weight than resizing the image itself :D

Comment: Are they getting distorted as the device is turned or ?

Comment: @impression7vx : there will be slight difference in the dimension of it :) If I use scaleToFill image looks distorted as the imageView won't follow the aspect ration of image but if I choose ScaleToFit image maintains its aspect ratio but leaves little space in image view and this space varies for various orientations as I explained above :)

Comment: Ahh! `scaleToFit` will definitely be your best option! Here is an option, instead of saving so much data.

Comment: @impression7vx : Yup as suggested by deadbeef am hoping on it but then again this little gap in the image view will continue to persist even after having it set as scaleToFit. What is more unfortunate in this case is I have buttons on the two sides of images as a result even the slightest change in the image size makes the UI look ugly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this is a bad idea, but potential options.

You could

1) Get the original image size.
Save this.

func resetImage() {

2) Determine if picture width > height

3) If width > height, then you know it is gonna be a longer picture. Determine how long you would like it. Let's say you want the wider pictures about 1/10*Width of a cell

4) Determine the height of the image accordingly. ((1/10)/widthOfCell)*imageHeight

5) If (width > height) imageView.frame = CGRect(0, 0, 1/10*widthCell, height)

6) imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit, imageView.image = UIImage(named: "awesome")

7) Possibly save imageView.size to use incase another rotation.

This allows you to change just the imageView instead of saving the image data, hopefully removing the white space. Comment and lemme see whatcha think.

Comment: Thanks buddy :) I appreciate your effort :) But I don't think I can change the imageView size once it is rendered as many other UI Components are associated with it using auto layout constraint. So changing imageView frame will break few of them and might lead to strain o/p. Second thing : yes you are right that it removes the white space but in order for this to work I'll have to do this calculation and resize the imageView for each orientation isn't it buddy :) Anyway I'll give a try :) Hence up vote :)

Comment: Haha no problem! I hope you can do this, as I have done it myself, just not with buttons around it or anything :P I don't prefer to use constrains or the storyboard much, just do a `imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(...))` then when I need to change it I can simply say `imageView.frame` but I did it on a button click, not on a rotation! But let me know if it did or did not work, and we will see what we can do from there!

Comment: You may have to re-adjust the buttons on the sides, if they are dependent on the `imageView.frame`!

Comment: Sure buddy :) I'll update you tomo on it :) Unfortunately I can't walk away neither from story board or from auto layout constraint as my whole team is using it :) any way thanks for your time :) I'll let you know tomo as am signing off now :P